# Has anyone encountered roughness in moka pot with mold?

Tags: equipment, moka, cleaning

I used moka pot (bialetti) for the first time then I rinsed it with tap water and let it on the bench.

One week later when I took it to make coffee I saw the botom-most part of the moka pot which was molded. It was something like turqoise color.
Then I washed it with with detergent. What I saw afterwards was terrible. It was like I was using it for years. Roughnesses occured on the surface and there are lots of partially distributed spots that I can not wash away.

I want to ask you did someone happen to something like that ? Is it my fault that I did not dry it myself and this happened ? Can it be the cause of a non-original product or maybe it happened just because it is almunium and wet?

Thank you.

[image: stained moka pot]

Comment: You may also want to see this question: http://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/1847/moka-pot-buildup

Comment: I can't explain the turquoise tint, but this is merely tarnish. It's difficult to keep Aluminum looking good, but it's generally not harmful and nearly impossible to "undo". See other linked answers for more detail. Interesting question; come back again!